# lib\app_error.c|49|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void' Nortic Semi example

Tags: c++, c, nrf51

I'm trying to use nordic semiconductor example showing how to use button handling library: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nrf51-app-button-example
compiler gives me error like in the title. I'm trying to find missing coma or semicolon but I can't see any mistake.

app_error.c

```
/* Copyright (c) 2014 Nordic Semiconductor. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * The information contained herein is property of Nordic Semiconductor ASA.
 * Terms and conditions of usage are described in detail in NORDIC
 * SEMICONDUCTOR STANDARD SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT.
 *
 * Licensees are granted free, non-transferable use of the information. NO
 * WARRANTY of ANY KIND is provided. This heading must NOT be removed from
 * the file.
 *
 */

/** @file
 *
 * @defgroup app_error Common application error handler
 * @{
 * @ingroup app_common
 *
 * @brief Common application error handler.
 */

#include "nrf.h"
#include "app_error.h"
#include "compiler_abstraction.h"
#include "nordic_common.h"
#ifdef DEBUG
#include "bsp.h"

/* global error variables - in order to prevent removal by optimizers */
uint32_t m_error_code;
uint32_t m_line_num;
const uint8_t * m_p_file_name;
#endif

/**@brief Function for error handling, which is called when an error has occurred.
 *
 * @warning This handler is an example only and does not fit a final product. You need to analyze
 *          how your product is supposed to react in case of error.
 *
 * @param[in] error_code  Error code supplied to the handler.
 * @param[in] line_num    Line number where the handler is called.
 * @param[in] p_file_name Pointer to the file name.
 *
 * Function is implemented as weak so that it can be overwritten by custom application error handler
 * when needed.
 */

/*lint -save -e14 */
__WEAK void app_error_handler(uint32_t error_code, uint32_t line_num, const uint8_t * p_file_name)
{
    // On assert, the system can only recover with a reset.
#ifndef DEBUG
    NVIC_SystemReset();
#else

#ifdef BSP_DEFINES_ONLY
    LEDS_ON(LEDS_MASK);
#else
    UNUSED_VARIABLE(bsp_indication_set(BSP_INDICATE_FATAL_ERROR));
    // This call can be used for debug purposes during application development.
    // @note CAUTION: Activating this code will write the stack to flash on an error.
    //                This function should NOT be used in a final product.
    //                It is intended STRICTLY for development/debugging purposes.
    //                The flash write will happen EVEN if the radio is active, thus interrupting
    //                any communication.
    //                Use with care. Uncomment the line below to use.
    //ble_debug_assert_handler(error_code, line_num, p_file_name);
#endif // BSP_DEFINES_ONLY

    m_error_code = error_code;
    m_line_num = line_num;
    m_p_file_name = p_file_name;

    UNUSED_VARIABLE(m_error_code);
    UNUSED_VARIABLE(m_line_num);
    UNUSED_VARIABLE(m_p_file_name);
    __disable_irq();
    while(1) ;
#endif // DEBUG
}
/*lint -restore */
```

app_error.h

```
/* Copyright (c) 2013 Nordic Semiconductor. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * The information contained herein is property of Nordic Semiconductor ASA.
 * Terms and conditions of usage are described in detail in NORDIC
 * SEMICONDUCTOR STANDARD SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT.
 *
 * Licensees are granted free, non-transferable use of the information. NO
 * WARRANTY of ANY KIND is provided. This heading must NOT be removed from
 * the file.
 *
 */

/** @file
 *
 * @defgroup app_error Common application error handler
 * @{
 * @ingroup app_common
 *
 * @brief Common application error handler and macros for utilizing a common error handler.
 */

#ifndef APP_ERROR_H__
#define APP_ERROR_H__

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "nrf_error.h"

/**@brief Function for error handling, which is called when an error has occurred.
 *
 * @param[in] error_code  Error code supplied to the handler.
 * @param[in] line_num    Line number where the handler is called.
 * @param[in] p_file_name Pointer to the file name.
 */
void app_error_handler(uint32_t error_code, uint32_t line_num, const uint8_t * p_file_name);

/**@brief Macro for calling error handler function.
 *
 * @param[in] ERR_CODE Error code supplied to the error handler.
 */
#ifdef DEBUG
#define APP_ERROR_HANDLER(ERR_CODE)                         \
    do                                                      \
    {                                                       \
        app_error_handler((ERR_CODE), __LINE__, (uint8_t*) __FILE__);  \
    } while (0)
#else
#define APP_ERROR_HANDLER(ERR_CODE)                         \
    do                                                      \
    {                                                       \
        app_error_handler((ERR_CODE), 0, 0);  \
    } while (0)
#endif
/**@brief Macro for calling error handler function if supplied error code any other than NRF_SUCCESS.
 *
 * @param[in] ERR_CODE Error code supplied to the error handler.
 */
#define APP_ERROR_CHECK(ERR_CODE)                           \
    do                                                      \
    {                                                       \
        const uint32_t LOCAL_ERR_CODE = (ERR_CODE);         \
        if (LOCAL_ERR_CODE != NRF_SUCCESS)                  \
        {                                                   \
            APP_ERROR_HANDLER(LOCAL_ERR_CODE);              \
        }                                                   \
    } while (0)

/**@brief Macro for calling error handler function if supplied boolean value is false.
 *
 * @param[in] BOOLEAN_VALUE Boolean value to be evaluated.
 */
#define APP_ERROR_CHECK_BOOL(BOOLEAN_VALUE)                   \
    do                                                        \
    {                                                         \
        const uint32_t LOCAL_BOOLEAN_VALUE = (BOOLEAN_VALUE); \
        if (!LOCAL_BOOLEAN_VALUE)                             \
        {                                                     \
            APP_ERROR_HANDLER(0);                             \
        }                                                     \
    } while (0)

#endif // APP_ERROR_H__

/** @} */
```

main.c

```
**********************************************************************/

#include "nrf.h"
#include "ble.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "app_button.h"
#include "boards.h"
#include "app_gpiote.h"
#include "app_timer.h"
#include "pca10028.h"



#define APP_TIMER_PRESCALER             0  // Value of the RTC1 PRESCALER register.
#define APP_TIMER_MAX_TIMERS            1  // Maximum number of simultaneously created timers.
#define APP_TIMER_OP_QUEUE_SIZE         2  // Size of timer operation queues.
#define BUTTON_DEBOUNCE_DELAY           50 // Delay from a GPIOTE event until a button is reported as pushed.
#define APP_GPIOTE_MAX_USERS            1  // Maximum number of users of the GPIOTE handler.


/*
 * Handler to be called when button is pushed.
 * param[in]   pin_no           The pin number where the event is genereated
 * param[in]   button_action    Is the button pushed or released
 */
static void button_handler(uint8_t pin_no, uint8_t button_action)
{
    if(button_action == APP_BUTTON_PUSH)
    {
        switch(pin_no)
        {
            case BUTTON_1:
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_1);
                break;
            case BUTTON_2:
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
                break;
            case BUTTON_3:
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_3);
                break;
            case BUTTON_4:
                nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_4);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the clock.
 */
void init_clock()
{
    NRF_CLOCK->LFCLKSRC            = (CLOCK_LFCLKSRC_SRC_Xtal << CLOCK_LFCLKSRC_SRC_Pos);
    NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_LFCLKSTARTED = 0;
    NRF_CLOCK->TASKS_LFCLKSTART    = 1;
    while (NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_LFCLKSTARTED == 0); // Wait for clock to start
}

/**
 * Initialize all four LEDs on the nRF51 DK.
 */
void init_leds()
{
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_1);
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_2);
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_3);
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_4);
    nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_1);
    nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_2);
    nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_3);
    nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_4);
}

/**
 * Function for application main entry.
 */
int main(void)
{
    init_leds();
    init_clock();

    uint32_t err_code;

    // Button configuration structure.
    static app_button_cfg_t p_button[] = {  {BUTTON_1, APP_BUTTON_ACTIVE_LOW, NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP, button_handler},
                                            {BUTTON_2, APP_BUTTON_ACTIVE_LOW, NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP, button_handler},
                                            {BUTTON_3, APP_BUTTON_ACTIVE_LOW, NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP, button_handler},
                                            {BUTTON_4, APP_BUTTON_ACTIVE_LOW, NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP, button_handler}};

    // Macro for initializing the application timer module.
    // It will handle dimensioning and allocation of the memory buffer required by the timer, making sure that the buffer is correctly aligned. It will also connect the timer module to the scheduler (if specified).
    APP_TIMER_INIT(APP_TIMER_PRESCALER, APP_TIMER_MAX_TIMERS, APP_TIMER_OP_QUEUE_SIZE, NULL);

    // Macro for initializing the GPIOTE module.
    // It will handle dimensioning and allocation of the memory buffer required by the module, making sure that the buffer is correctly aligned.
    APP_GPIOTE_INIT(APP_GPIOTE_MAX_USERS);

    // Initializing the buttons.
    err_code = app_button_init(p_button, sizeof(p_button) / sizeof(p_button[0]), BUTTON_DEBOUNCE_DELAY);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    // Enabling the buttons.
    err_code = app_button_enable();
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    while(true)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
__WEAK void app_error_handler(/*...*/)
```

`__WEAK` macro is not defined. Check where `__WEAK` is declared and make sure the header file is included.

Comment: Also try replacing it with `__attribute__((weak))`

Comment: Thanks for fast reply - both tips were helpful!